# Why I can't post array and single value in the same form by ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I have  this scripts:

```
<script>
function send_mail() {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/software/hsn/send_mail.php",
data:  $('[name="check_id[]"]').serialize(), // post array
{email : $("#email").val()} // post single value

success: function() {

// content
}
}
</script>
```

When I post form, only one control was posted. Example:

```
$('[name="check_id[]"]').serialize(), // post array
```

or

```
{email : $("#email").val()} // post single value
```

Normally, the last control was effected, even when I changed their position.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for data is ***wrong***. 
Data can be a **PlainObject or String or Array**, but not multiple comma separated values.
Correct syntax for data is

```
data: {name1: value1, name2: value2},
```

So your syntax should be

```
{name : $('[name="check_id[]"]').serialize(),email : $("#email").val()},
```

Check out jQuery ajax documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

change data:

```
 $('[name="check_id[]"]').serialize(), // post array
{email : $("#email").val()}
```

to

```
data: {check_id: $('[name="check_id[]"]').serialize(),email : $("#email").val()}
```

It will take all the values.
Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/)

```
data: $('[name="check_id[]"]')
      .add('#email') // add the element to the collection
      .serializeArray() // serialize now
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, specially to Mr Twain. My problem has resolved.

I use this script:

```
data:  $('[name="check_id[]"]').serialize() + "&email=" + $("#email").val(),
```

It's worked.